# Is it possible to write cross platform "Launcher" app in C++ without directly interacting with the OS?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-platform, launcher

I have recently been writing a launcher for a process on Linux. The basic idea is simple:

- The launcher process gets started at the system startup and keeps running
- After doing some basic setup, it launches a headless process that is supposed to run in the background continuously
- Launcher process monitors the newly launched process and restarts it if it's crashed (and periodically 'talks' to the process)

The only way I can think of is using a named pipe and then `exec`ing the process using that on Linux, also using a `popen` to get the `ps` command output back and parsing it to see the process is running or not. However, it seems less robust and certainly not cross platform.

So my question is, is there a proper C++ way of doing the same that is cross platform (since I need to support the windows too) and not hacky. Any library that I can use for such a task?

Comment: Standard C++ has no concept of starting another process (except for system(), which obviously won't work), so if your question is about Standard C++, then no.

Comment: Looking at it from the other direction: How do you launch the launcher? Plenty of ways to run a program when a user logs on in Windows, but to run without a user I think you're doomed to a service and there is no way you're getting that cross platform. The guts of the code, sure that can be cross platform, but the service wrapper is doomed to be Windows-specific.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I understand. I meant to ask C++ accessible way, as in, a library or framework that can take care of the boilerplate code.

Comment: @16 Possibly http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html